# Using Pandas; not sure whether to use map or add with these dataframes

Tags: excel, pandas

I have two data frames that were read from excel.

```
df1
               SRD CIVF Test Case
0  9530\n3678\n549        CIV-016
1       9979\n9980        CIV-040
2       5231\n4455        CIV-177

df2
          SRD SRD CR 
0   549\n9980  CR181
1        4455  CR170
2  5231\n9979  CR190
```

For df1, I want to add a third column that will indicate the 'SRD CR' number  that references the same SRD as listed in the SRD column. Not sure if I should use the 'map' or 'add' Pandas function. The dataframe as shown in df3 is basically what I am looking for. DF3 will written back into excel. Also, I expect retaining multiple values in the same cell (for Excel) will be tricky.

```
df3
               SRD CIVF Test Case  SRD CR
0  9530\n3678\n549        CIV-016  CR181
1       9979\n9980        CIV-040  CR190\nCR181
2       5231\n4455        CIV-177  CR170\nCR190
```

Comment: Are you open to having one SRD per row, with other variables repeating as necessary (this would be "long format"), instead of SRD being stuck in an unwieldy string in a single row for each unique `Test Case` (in df1) and `SRD CR` (in df2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a good reason to keep `SRD` values buried in strings in single rows, I would convert `df1` and `df2` so that each row has a single `SRD` value. Then you can merge on `SRD`:

```
# Split all strings between '\n' into their own columns
split1 = df1['SRD'].str.split('\\\\n', expand=True)
split2 = df2['SRD'].str.split('\\\\n', expand=True)

split1
      0     1     2
0  9530  3678   549
1  9979  9980  None
2  5231  4455  None

split2
      0     1
0   549  9980
1  4455  None
2  5231  9979


# Concatenate the above split columns onto the right sides of
# the original DFs
catted1 = pd.concat([df1, split1], axis=1)
catted2 = pd.concat([df2, split2], axis=1)

catted1
               SRD  CIVF Test Case     0     1     2
0  9530\n3678\n549   NaN   CIV-016  9530  3678   549
1       9979\n9980   NaN   CIV-040  9979  9980  None
2       5231\n4455   NaN   CIV-177  5231  4455  None

catted2
          SRD SRD CR     0     1
0   549\n9980  CR181   549  9980
1        4455  CR170  4455  None
2  5231\n9979  CR190  5231  9979


# Give each SRD its own row
melted1 = pd.melt(catted1, 
                  id_vars=['CIVF', 'Test Case', 'SRD'], 
                  value_name='Shared_SRDs')\
          .drop('variable', axis=1).dropna(subset=['Shared_SRDs'])
melted2 = pd.melt(catted2.drop('SRD', axis=1), 
                  id_vars=['SRD CR'],
                  value_name='Shared_SRDs')\
          .drop('variable', axis=1).dropna()

melted1
   CIVF Test Case   SRD
0   NaN   CIV-016  9530
1   NaN   CIV-040  9979
2   NaN   CIV-177  5231
3   NaN   CIV-016  3678
4   NaN   CIV-040  9980
5   NaN   CIV-177  4455
6   NaN   CIV-016   549

melted2
  SRD CR Shared_SRDs
0  CR181         549
1  CR170        4455
2  CR190        5231
3  CR181        9980
5  CR190        9979


# Merge on SRD values
merged = melted1.merge(melted2, on='SRD').sort_values(['Test Case', 'SRD CR']).reset_index(drop=True)

merged
   CIVF Test Case              SRD Shared_SRDs SRD CR
0   NaN   CIV-016  9530\n3678\n549         549  CR181
1   NaN   CIV-040       9979\n9980        9980  CR181
2   NaN   CIV-040       9979\n9980        9979  CR190
3   NaN   CIV-177       5231\n4455        4455  CR170
4   NaN   CIV-177       5231\n4455        5231  CR190
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for sharing this code.I am new to Python, so it will take me a bit to digest all this code. Your method is to move the data to columns and back to row. As I mentioned in another comment above, I was considering to move the SRD# to individual row, but then the worksheet would get really big as you could have sometimes 50 SRD entries for some items. It is convenient to have all the data contained in one Excel row. But I will definitely consider this alternative.
Question, why wouldn't the map function work for this example? Is Merge a lot more easier to work with?

Comment: Peter, I just tried the first line of code for split1, but all it does is remove the second  column. The first column remains intact. Is there another line of code that is needed?

Comment: @GusG, thanks for clarifying the problem at hand. I imagine it's also possible to solve it using `map`, though the first approach that I thought of used `merge`. As for the first line, maybe you need to run `split1 = df1['SRD'].str.split('\n', expand=True)` -- replace `'\\\\n'` with `'\n'` and see if that works. (I had to use `'\\\\n'` because of how I imported your example data.)

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, the command line should be ... split1 = df1['SRD'].str.split('\n', expand=True)